# Handling task schedules

Tags: .net, sql-server

I'm looking for more of a discussion of conceptual ideas here, rather than necessarily specifics (though specifics are certainly welcome as well). A frequent requirement in an application environment is the need to be able to run specific tasks on a set schedule (Every monday at 3:00 PM, every weekday at 6:30 PM, once at 2:00 PM today, etc).

Now, in my environment, I have built a windows service that runs on the application server to handle these events. Currently it uses a timer that expires once per hour and checks if anything needs to be done. Currently all of these events are using hard coded checks of the date/time/weekday etc to perform their tasks. Now, obviously, with a timer that runs once per hour, my resolution of when an event runs is any time from when it is scheduled to 1 hour later. For my current tasks, this is fine.

What I would like to do is be able to handle tasks that are scheduled arbitrarily, and with a better resolution on time. Now, the improved resolution will simply be a matter of having a timer that expires every minute to check if a task needs to run. However, the first requirement, being able to schedule these things arbitrarily, is a bit more complicated.

The application is connected to a SQL database, and the front end is all in a web based ASP.Net application, so the user interface portion shouldn't be an issue. I am wondering the following:

I would like to, at minimum, be able to handle schedules of the complexity that applications like SQL Server Agent allow, that is, allow for a recurring item with a start date and end date (or no end date), a frequency (daily, weekly, monthly), specific weekdays selectable for weekly scheduling, etc. Now, clearly, I could just have a field for each of these elements in a database table, along with a "last run time" and "next run time" column, but that seems grossly inefficient to me.

So my specific questions are:
Are there any best practices for database data model design for storing scheduled tasks?

Are there any existing .Net libraries that I could use for storing these schedules on the front end, and then determining if it is time to run a particular job on the back end? I can certainly brute force this, but it seems like a common enough requirement, that there should likely be something out there to do a lot of the heavy lifting without having to "recreate the wheel".

Are there any pitfalls with handling this type of requirement that you have encountered that might not be obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Just use SQL Agent??? Or use a Windows Scheduled task... Consider also [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

What benefit do you gain from writing your own?

This is a harder problem that it seems so existing solutions should be leveraged. Your current idea of polling every minute is very inefficient and there are many subtle bugs when dealing with timing like this. Just write your jobs in a console app instead of a service and call it from an existing scheduler. You can make your front-end create the job using the SQL Agent / Scheduled Task / Hangfire interface if you want to keep custom front-end.

Windows Services are better suited for things that are running **all the time**, not on a schedule.